# How to access a UI element in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with a control (a TextView) with id `R.id.currentCycleIndicator` and want to programmatically set its value from within the fragment.

Both

- `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.currentCycleIndicator)` and
- `getView().findViewById(R.id.currentCycleIndicator)`

return null.

How can I get reference to that TextView inside the fragment code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try getting its value in onCreateView() callBack function of your Fragment like below :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentCycleIndicator);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I know I am opening a very old thread back again,,,but what if I have to access the textView from some other activity? How do I get the object of the current active fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by overriding the onViewCreated function as below :

```
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentCycleIndicator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inflate your view inside `onCreateView` and refer to your TextView from there.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutwheretextviewis, container, false);

            TextView text= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentCycleIndicator);
            return view;
}
```